# Editor functionality

Tags: buttons, ux-field, drag-n-drop, features, editor

We have an editor that allows you to build a static page.

On the left sidebar of the editor are buttons that allow you to change the colors, text, add images, etc. On the right is a preview of the page you are building.

On this left sidebar, is it ok to add links to Help or more info? I'm not sure when it is ok to mix product functionality and external links.

Here is a quick mockup:

[image]

Comment: Show us a mock of your efforts and thinking. There are many paths to effective design, but we should have more context for a better answer.

Comment: Thank you @MikeM, I have updated the question with a mockup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say yes its ok to add them (even preferable to keep user confidence high) but they should be visually separated to keep the functionality vs business intent obvious.

These type of links are often shown in smaller text, fixed to the bottom of the column vs the larger actions in your mockup.

Comment: Thanks, Bryce! Can you elaborate more on how this is "keeping user confidence high"?

Comment: Basically, you're telling the user "Its ok if you don't know how to do this, we've got your back" when you add help/tutorials/feedback type buttons. They just need to be separate from the tool interface :-)